# limit when $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \sum _{i=0} ^{n} \frac{1}{2^i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

limit when $$\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \sum _{i=0} ^{n} \frac{1}{2^i}$$
I intuitively know that the limit is 2 and that a series is convergent, but I do not know how to arrive at the result

Comment: I had wrong in writing, please check now

Comment: It’s a geometric series.  Search for that phrase and you’ll find everything you need.

Comment: It's geometric series, we know what the sum looks like. It's $\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$. Now take the limit

Comment: This is such a standard series....  it's literally everywhere.  Open your book... phone a friend, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Let $$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{2^i}$$

then

$$S_{n+1}=1 +\frac 12 S_n$$

The limit  $L$ should satisfy

$$L=1+\frac L2$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without invoking the magic words "geometric series", note that if $S = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^i}$ then $$\frac{1}{2}S = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2^i} = \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^i}}_{S} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{2^0}$$
which you can rearrange.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula for the sum of a geometric series:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_0\cdot r^i=\frac{a_0(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}$$

Here, $a_0=1$ and $r=\frac 1 2$, so we have:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^i}=\frac{1\cdot \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\right)}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$

Now, we need to find:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$

Since $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we get:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)=2(1-0)=2$$

Comment: It is $n+1$ instead of $n$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Thanks for the catch! I've fixed the error in my answer above.